# Deploying a Sinatra App to Heroku With Bundler -- Gems not found

Tags: deployment, heroku, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

I am deploying a Sinatra app to Heroku. I am using Bundler for my dependencies. When I run it on my machine, it works with no problem. I launch it with this

config.ru

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler"

require "net/http"
require "uri"

Bundler.require

require './application'
run Sinatra::Application
```

and this

Gemfile

```
source :gemcutter

gem "sinatra"
gem "aws-s3"
gem "zipruby"
gem "bson_ext"
gem "mongo"
gem "json"
gem "sinatra-subdomain"
```

When I push it, there are no errors. It shows the bundle being installed fine. Then, when I visit the URL, I get an Application Error. Viewing `heroku logs`, the error is `Unexpected error while processing request: undefined method 'subdomain' for main:Object`. That refers to the sinatra-subdomain gem that I am using. If I comment out the subdomain section, the next gem, aws/s3, gives an error. I couldn't find anything in the documentation to help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the same version of Ruby?  Compare `heroku stack` on heroku, and `ruby -v` on your local machine.  I'd also post a much longer stacktrace from the heroku logs: `heroku logs -n10000`

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I had 1.9.3, needed 1.9.2. Worked Fine.